# How to add a discord id/username

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to add a username or id to the code so that when I (or somebody else) does .d @username, the selfbot does the whole ".accept" and "u 4" response.

Code:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()
b = Bot(command_prefix = ".d")

@b.event
async def on_ready():
    print("rdy")

@b.event
async def on_message(message)
    if message.content == ".d":
        await message.channel.send(".accept")
        await message.channel.send("u 4")

b.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"), bot = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use commands it makes things alot easier.

```
@b.command(aliases=['.d'])
async def d(ctx, member: discord.Member):
      await ctx.send(".accept")
      await ctx.send("u 4")
```

I added the `.d` in aliases cause you cannot have a function starting with `.` . Here is the link for more information. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=group#commands

Comment: Adding that in place of the second event returns the following error:

`File "main.py", line 15
    b.commands(aliases=['.d'])
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I also had a question about the command. Does the code u provided allow the selfbot to respond to any member pinged by .d @username, or do I have to input the username I want in place of something? In other words, will it respond to me saying .d @123 and .d @456, or do I have to input a specific username that I want it to respond to? If it is the latter, where would I input that and would I do so with or without the @?

Comment: For clarity, this is my new code:

https://pastebin.com/N8cZpJHe

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the @. I have edited the code accordingly. No need to add event. I'm not sure about what you are asking exactly. Could you elaborate a little bit on what exactly it is you want.

Comment: I was just asking whether i could mention any member after ".d" and have it respond, or if I had to specify a specific member, but I think I understand it now.

I made the fixes of removing the event and adding the @ to the b.commands, but I now get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    @b.commands(aliases=['.d'])
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable`

my code once again: https://pastebin.com/N8cZpJHe